# Toolbar has padding left and right on Tablet size only

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-toolbar

I have this weird issue wherein a padding is added only on tablet size devices.

My container already has the following code:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tbLogin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp">
```

and this is working fine on Phone size devices.

This issue only occurs on tablet size and I dont know why? Is there a specific property for tablet devices to disable it?

Comment: how are you adding this to your container layout?

Comment: there's no problem on how to add this in the container layout. but if you want to i use <include>. The previewer itself shows a space left and right

Comment: this is definitely reproducing.

Answer (score 3):

Finally found the solution. Adding padding = 0dp solve the unwanted space on Tablet size